# Perpendicularity and Parallelism in Barycentric Coordinates

Tags: barycentric-coordinates

Given the barycentric equation of a line $l$ and barycentric coordinates of any point $P$ in the plane, how does one find the equation of the line passing through $P$ and
(i) perpendicular to $l$?
(ii) parallel to $l$ ?

Comment: I know how to use the perpendicularity criterion if we're dealing with Barycentric Displacement vectors, but could anyone give a slight idea on how to deal directly with lines?